Inverse Laplace Transform of Nightmare Function
I have the following very cumbersome s domain function that I have tried to take the inverse Laplace transform of in MATLAB with ilapace() to no avail.
F(s)=
341605214072379198780660402671139/(2658455991569831745807614120560689152*(s^2 + 2544453722359136646330665415746689/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) + (8985114956909607*s)/(4722366482869645213696*(s^2 + 1298190674673028901189115008034025/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) - 253892963471840763404150278125525/(1361129467683753853853498429727072845824*(s^2 + 1298190674673028901189115008034025/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) + (8094331267816079*s)/(4722366482869645213696*(s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) + (1751413390701931*s)/(590295810358705651712*(s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249/5192296858534827628530496329220096)) - (1481993660727327*s)/(18446744073709551616*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) - (8382805990219283*s)/(18889465931478580854784*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/5192296858534827628530496329220096)) + (6636546638004119*s)/(2361183241434822606848*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/1298074214633706907132624082305024)) + (266882459740871*s)/(147573952589676412928*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/324518553658426726783156020576256)) - 1183305847853425397838416597475/(5316911983139663491615228241121378304*(s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) + 164999891240961755056704817847229/(1361129467683753853853498429727072845824*(s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249/5192296858534827628530496329220096)) + 57811081336688308673333233147211/(2658455991569831745807614120560689152*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) - 43757485455465093476200298937609/(170141183460469231731687303715884105728*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/5192296858534827628530496329220096)) - 56913782995703463597419570429039/(340282366920938463463374607431768211456*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/1298074214633706907132624082305024)) + 37262669743910938055477278747457/(680564733841876926926749214863536422912*(s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361/324518553658426726783156020576256)) + 6068698292039585/(1180591620717411303424*s) - (3579252204516133*s)/(9223372036854775808*(s^2 + 2544453722359136646330665415746689/20769187434139310514121985316880384)) + (7206082638085769*2^(1/2)*((20769187434139310514121985316880384*s^2 + 2544453722359136646330665415746689)*(20769187434139310514121985316880384*s^2 + 1298190674673028901189115008034025)*(5192296858534827628530496329220096*s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249)*(20769187434139310514121985316880384*s^2 + 467348642882290404428081402892249)*(324518553658426726783156020576256*s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361)*(1298074214633706907132624082305024*s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361)*(5192296858534827628530496329220096*s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361)*(20769187434139310514121985316880384*s^2 + 51927626986921156047564600321361)*(s^2 + 2*s + 2)*(1299492859693575429466312044807397557334372067118505551056435163367011583011004810682862311096337888441675112062006212309658975362047269131848954380353674999345874426521271458168266497714385369174192217755598598120708881418114560224944492107333218909995733397700244655833088*s^15 - 437323100133687102961868334506707984508011519206504589452569629839487425428669086784009207076307440311630350024224564225283243242022258091552598097868826423480595424756948627047993949337644351748044728818367914737198250565276868871245300862269203567700002974995093347368960*s^14 + 503778889559224829593327808289874769809621237667923632598703476552296405832980494362354149306849578145632151120833750417944941858785394956996807628704803974445856368597601776806590548048998073143943166390995760417720857530577829376077386224311970590081283805667586121662464*s^13 - 169602788785932515703876765731731724140566295191046065337500647642040198313427501064890315241565845150040909307998489131405475951710915730468623357712198921593494710850625913040201698324300515331989074047341180333755980204471782932146242989242520345535603123205950438113280*s^12 + 71770876414755714626142962163368169571882603240113134210123414328010201244110210677652883433820073256392399747194903806778517246531250366845711771762265994845630566772350772086543591876553889957175026856576013750958544719952324130740704332571162135974071152696911084912640*s^11 - 24181630169616742356935951766955906379350766980353048918863947203006983352396124880849127241612782408755843970215596627142324515074230610280854503177457537997997929925188692415026729584636112762778096314611727696187594446970035529109597299324809322605236571016442727628800*s^10 + 4819885647730855137600307861127543078890830249141271401276362997889914401215746128747921145788563441948155618756649605075206474704706357869528013047168552347862281186062995892867920421255465245669163792925493349582699654174292831666964145992458116200609555976588049252352*s^9 - 1625143914191597863388637161771993755071774691344113352032237612778663106325215605413694079569408389294946614353637427218543706380068272566412682306347772800249383554113985007515354049156784537141559702856710740561786522799402757139682089960094083409289374244745447997440*s^8 + 160827017300848328889699523666637971364224813819329357510196158326755887124346382975470758958141788284075502885110079041340882627248517475616231323151458139851004481897369925576071371861190584514262129968200931619180274387847212267806415677545438172063249865166800551936*s^7 - 54229458514142261273079319198346634329356765728882666699409243709710462936172212486384375808318601752119825779952105560648440061967651627248221805826957213747796032086812963525595143299850425915283975291223977366417188938856833999469928436134438426709393789767563345920*s^6 + 2558916146169913199080132809768243505683893773871502482871607503994124353584960882856733280107727514606575491865108049437159292226071023874009434780899014714573143273847159628382763109567808886477254394700384761356091250715456823282110283507462143561256797460636893184*s^5 - 861154162768351907737516122961644418061230982550512915310788883617498226752103750558331135082334098609960881997713205869337450644641752027238234076250130577340177081333291155457564777414748024364315224143635067749062019785403502480753621255016298536417516828732948480*s^4 + 16806705177985555004774875580326832815955373789411951424797528168012434221231251105713874383664180001540739985928136439158232826163140831141329542416267428353027794669370573892375879274766366750595734210730553597337271804115904383963156329295726790047468169289793536*s^3 - 5615512768642804740365975621142323159085482541669158311198463194949745591882484415214284099299781341295842204598336688624783124843887391697101220071660584475837817628592201164176945276335633320221647859937889049934729831252646309434109434351747347911468790600171520*s^2 + 31463493338544060795562253853888983905238587512212560717930105525771948253698071856633108609981471578116494658835080255868000504866169879992863501094136261218171435159438666885005294703683967579027319027999787547926542111302581746427066904306117914032122049331200*s - 10284218740299564149136054024233675232012222025369463779579473301194979797063839234348762602572393594213745848565027599530883767350929875823369707424590665738755749144255752678461523121943209069526572514896067360045126747471928824966650372092774102408765525828875))^(1/2))/(36893488147419103232*(2113178124542660985409359139666066426075389304144486088511842836106695610226899437897669023550628751578697579973028514715529390238010742149002155913851758307633546735996020336674926070705705764212096931632844753616592113171006246955353587595068145905958154323590951993344*s^18 + 4226356249085321970818718279332132852150778608288972177023685672213391220453798875795338047101257503157395159946057029431058780476021484298004311827703516615267093471992040673349852141411411528424193863265689507233184226342012493910707175190136291811916308647181903986688*s^17 + 5304173783076629106087647423681429085631443604954825276544220981788861486144093189933676173576432371986632617995303083151131970275415026084368868861470762922993034221141705745418783811537964141887516240305491458414563698822760299855207656856868800893973925092264815624192*s^16 + 2155635067982614270537858288698592466961329993331706199041070619150940531380588628276676252950349737658474916098492107440146379598787083572729114067534492615451881498299330144137863340253105226926644754079603902362758944961495611889000963333465018164115232890165823275008*s^15 + 2372565307402178079186380005277303063914653537580929122295853614930143252792571760174987253478771674770642225704566843276496613391699712538451356828452589698186334540537656113071162299933303982773673290758848546314586894333830530911369274561711565314787929730309628624896*s^14 + 433860478839127617297043433157421193906647088498445846509565991558405442823966263796622001056843874224334619212149471672700467585825257931444485521836194165468906084476651937866597919360397511694057073358489287903655898744669838044736622456493094301345393680287610699776*s^13 + 455961948985051134300933391743213952654154633195758309813530931885135779427220575824195625749005625292685783552536410331808871448065732303035928835856134118216788988720015796229719232666902273582184405715362280339367614870328669096088625195983485225666414576684272451584*s^12 + 44202940291847034007779917171585517495015089394624926607929880653460673206508624055147249384323502136702328680773877318216807724480948743182886628039879905495765808486727716726242626613009523776254664713745984871423432251317662102704005478980781848642041792793323503616*s^11 + 45420035398608574733213709895559451167507909103482840277285933741245222816697051766452401509095621016462178929777261732199690076957430081170408385452305062442789474581739304804850554696174996230429697135221540828421232233938208233384621932448729335924019522692351787008*s^10 + 2434190213523081450867585447947867344985639417715827338712106175569099220376855422610304249544237759519700498006768827965764704952962675975043514824850313894047332190023176157215856166330944908350064842951111913995599965241092261361232906935894974563955459798056566784*s^9 + 2470056429607635688097965131151730513189279043647587555510198907807156043313317655700591798013777398715166198242770889966211760273023538531878182334714701681286332023757949832904879492080998875115182879303156998963342854276485910400308736649097455064979170583962976256*s^8 + 71732432169108474460759366407726336407279251863520433596185464476113645872924466180575096939079278390931400472004124000894110640121725113669335019728775574477999667469547351378046651500107933530236072704090169935485778070787298078151659426404961002047421571812818944*s^7 + 72257432412069891078419530991850130303429017627978620425723713425579556897495198442654199650965011636338462524724619963230751286655393073213618181128634691811772040328395209137826496813726070511879302378808642133289878088458045489084995331790416926554512031450398720*s^6 + 1050000485922833235320329168247587792299531528916373659076497898931822049141464524158205423771466490814124105440991924673281293067335919088566322799718234667544745717695715519559690627236273963286459349436944395608200035341494821866671810770911849014180919275159552*s^5 + 1053205197910460883970913520860663049989537529236321516559565726655794435780107002082105908760933093174414577187655495999851101827249354143835980412716609502907162170220916693045835080230766005646144691336855896602842771592460572085187118315806966745128536027168768*s^4 + 6409423975255297301168705226150515380012000639895714966135655447944773277284955847800969978933204720580943493327142653139617519826870110539315225996749670724832905050402346972288905988984084719370683799823001989285472501931500437030615089790235461895233504018432*s^3 + 6414669741319133597992495118647432692568199031224582125145388369851944471266507056898403395022813792297134259649029263278439754975872039533673258874770731199058790403824561689164015282368340127751686698761629142470752511987542841587908235945712842796677352965657*s^2 + 10491532127672593647579784993834625112396782657734318019465843814342387963102418194866832179218143432381532643773220277644470298003857988716065756042120948451770706844429433750218586768510816762005797877254306370560020112084809114586292310954761802887697894450*s + 10491532127672593647579784993834625112396782657734318019465843814342387963102418194866832179218143432381532643773220277644470298003857988716065756042120948451770706844429433750218586768510816762005797877254306370560020112084809114586292310954761802887697894450))

Is there other software I could use or anything else I can try in MATLAB to solve this garbage for f(t) using the inverse Laplace transform?
